# Creating a generic CRUD class in .net and need to set a flag in the table instead of deleting

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I have a lot of tables that I need to do CRUD operations on.  So I created a base class for basic CRUD method.

```
public abstract class OTCCrudBaseClass<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly SpkContext _context;
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _entities;

    public OTCCrudBaseClass(SpkContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await _entities.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
    {
        return await _entities.FindAsync(id);
    }

    public async Task InsertAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        await _entities.AddAsync(entity);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task UpdateAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        _entities.Attach(entity);
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task DeleteAsync(Guid id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = await _entities.FindAsync(id);
        //Do not delete, set the enabled flag to 0
        //_entities.Remove(entityToDelete);
        
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

However, on the delete method, I don't want to delete the record. Most of the tables that have delete actions on them have a flag called "Active"  I want to set that flag to 0 to indicate it is not active in the system, but still available for reporting or if we are going to reactivate an old record for some reason.  How would I do this here? The entity is generic, so I could reflect against it, but that seems to be expensive just to set a flag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Generic implementation when only some entities use the soft-delete Active flag is going to be a bit of a pain. Generic should be used when *all* target types can be treated identically, where you will likely have situations where some entities should be deleted, others should be marked inactive, and others likely should be prevented from being deleted.

Ideally if you are using a Generic pattern you should have a base contract interface to identify your Entities, such as IEntity, so that the generic methods can apply a  `where TEntity : IEntity` rather than just `class`. From there, we can have an `ISoftDeleteEntity` which extends `IEntity` for classes that support soft-delete, and if there are entities that should *not* be deleted, then something like an `INoDeleteEntity` for those. ISoftDeleteEntity would expose the common Active flag:

```
public interface ISoftDeleteEntity : IEntity
{
    bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

Now when you go to perform your Delete method:

```
public async Task DeleteAsync(Guid id)
{
    if (typeof(INoDeleteEntity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity))
       throw new InvalidOperation($"{typeof(TEntity).Name} should not be deleted.");
    TEntity entityToDelete = await _entities.FindAsync(id);
    if (typeof(ISoftDeleteEntity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity))
        ((ISoftDeleteEntity)entityToDelete).Active = false;
    else
        _entities.Remove(entityToDelete);

     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Disclaimer: The above is written from memory so it may need some tweaking. :)

If you want to support re-activating entities, you would need similar conditional logic. Mixing and matching soft-delete and hard-delete entities with generic methods is not something I recommend doing as soft-delete entities likely need other considerations such as automatically filtering `.Where(x => x.Active)` by default, which is something that isn't needed for hard-delete or no-delete entity types. I do not recommend using Generic patterns at all with EF as Generics should apply solely to objects that can be treated identically, not merely similarly.